# How to use the mojang api in p5.js

Tags: javascript, minecraft, p5.js

I'm trying to use the mojang api to get usernames into UUIDs, but when I try to call the API using this code:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    loadJSON("http://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/jukebro", gotData, "jsonp")
}

function draw() {
    background(255, 255, 255)
}


function gotData(data) {
    console.log(data)
}
```

This code should work as far as I know, but when I try to run it I get this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/jukebro' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:49942' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

p5.js:23255 GET http://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/jukebro net::ERR_FAILED
```

anybody know what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your not giving enough information to help anyone properly understand you need to supply the version and what you expect and as much info as you can supply us

Comment: sorry about that, its fine though because I fixed it